# use keyboard shortcuts validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to validate my input on keypress.

My Java code for just numbers is this:

```
function numberValidate(evt) {
      var theEvent = evt || window.event;
      var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
      var key1 = key;
      key = String.fromCharCode( key );

      var regex = /^[0-9\u0008\u0009\u0016]/;

      if(key1 == 46 || key1 == 8 || key1 == 9 || key1 == 16 || key1 == 37 || key1 == 39 || key1 == 17 || key1 == 36 || key1 == 35)
        return false;

      if( !regex.test(key) ) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
      }
    }
```

and for letters, numbers, space, period and Arabic letters is this:

```
function textValidate(evt) {
      var theEvent = evt || window.event;
      var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
      var key1 = key;
      key = String.fromCharCode( key );

      var regex = /^[0-9a-zA-Z\u0600-\u06FF\u0008\u0009\u0016\. -]/;
      if(key1 == 46 || key1 == 8 || key1 == 9 || key1 == 16 || key1 == 37 || key1 == 39 || key1 == 17 || key1 == 36 || key1 == 35)
        return false;

      if( !regex.test(key)) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
      }
    }
```

Now, my questions are:

- Am I right or I have to change some parts of my code, why?
- I want to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in numbers part but as I didn't allow to use letters, so it won't let me to use them in some browser like Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull out the common bits as another function so you add tests without too much code duplication

```
function commonPermitted(e) {
    var arr = [
        8, // backspace
        9, // tab
        16, // shift
        17, // ctrl
        35, // end
        36, // home
        37, // left
        39, // right
        46, // del
        // you may want to permit enter/return here too
    ];
    if (arr.indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1)
        return true;
    if (e.ctrlKey && ['a', 'c', 'v', 'x'].indexOf(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toLowerCase()) !== -1)
        return true;
    return false;
}

function numberValidate(e) {
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    if (commonPermitted(e)) return;
    if (!/^[0-9]/.test(char))
        e.preventDefault();
}

function textValidate(e) {
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    if (commonPermitted(e)) return;
    if (!/^[0-9a-zA-Z\u0600-\u06FF. -]/.test(char))
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

Please note [`kbdEvent.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) and [`kbdEvent.which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) are **depreciated**, look into using [`kbdEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) or `kbdEvent.keyIdentifier` instead (but don't assume support of them)

Comment: I just used your ctrl part code and thanks for that part. If I want check whole the in put n paste, what could i do?
my mean use in paste function.
how can I write or change my function for check my value wont have special characters that i wont allow them.
thanks again